# can't use separate function files in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to declare the functions in separate files. In the code given below, my `main()` is defined in `main.cpp` and the `int addition(int x, int y)` is defined
in an another file named `function.cpp`.

**My code:**

**main.cpp**

```
#include "function.cpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a = 1;
int b = 15;

int sum = addition(a,b);
cout<<"\nSum = "<<sum<<"\n";

return 0;
}
```

**fucntion.cpp**

```
int addition(int x, int y)
{
int sum = x + y;
return sum;

}
```

But by using the above cod in Eclipse i am getting the following error. On the other hand, if i compile the code manually using `make`
through the linux terminal then, the same got works.

**ERROR:**

/home/eclipse_workspace/multiFiles/Debug/../funtion.cpp:9: multiple definition of `addition(int, int)'
./funtion.o:/home/eclipse_workspace/multiFiles/Debug/../funtion.cpp:9: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not recommended to include .cpp files. You should create header (.h) with declarations, put implementations to .cpp, like now and wherever you need to use it just include.h . You should also read about avoiding multiple includes by adding `#ifndef/#define/#endif`.

Update:

`#include` works in pre compiling phase and more or less it means "paste here what you have in file ...". So it copies function from one file and pastes to main file then compiles it. After this it compiles also cpp file with your function - also ok. Now comes linking: because of previous steps and copy-paste it has two definitions (actually two symbols) which has same name - that is causing the error and that's why we have headers :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am familiar with the structure but now i am trying to follow an another structure. I have edited my question, kindly have a look.

Comment: Thank u so much. As i understand, i shall only include a header file in the main programme. i tried this: included the header filename in the function file, declared the function in the headerfile, and included the header file in the main program. It worked. :)

Comment: what u told i understood, but the structure i have trouble with works well with 'geany' editor. The problem is with eclipse. ahouldn't the control flow of c++ b the same in both??

Comment: Are project files identical? I mean in case of make file/linking commands? Maybe in second IDE second file is not linked to executable?

Answer (score 0):

First create a header file, for example Addition.h and declare the function name inside it. Then make a file Addition.cpp and write the addition function implementation and then include the Addition.h in your main.cpp file.

The concept of using a header file is that you can use it anywhere else and is not limited to your main.cpp program file.

So, in short

Addition.h

```
class Addition { public: 
int addition(int a , int b); //function declaration
private: int result_; };
```

then  in Addition.cpp

```
#include Addition.h
int Addition::addition(int x, int y) {
// function implementation
}
```

in main.cpp

```
#include <Addition.h>
int main() 
{ int a=3, b=4, sum=0; 
Addition objAdd; //creation of object for class Addition
sum = objAdd.addition(a,b);
}
```

Hope this helps in structuring your code.